# iOS application transport security for charlesproxy

Tags: ios, tls1.2, app-transport-security

I am creating an application in iOS that needs to talk to my TLS-1.2 compliant server. After iOS 9, ATS(application transport security) introduced which by default enables this feature. I am not able to view the my packet easily using CharlesProxy anymore.

After searching around I found that we can disable it in the `info.plist` of my application temporary to see the traffic.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Connect to anything (for dev env only)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
```

If I understand it correctly, ATS is for data encryption and not the MITM. We need sort of SSL pinning to achieve MITM prevention. My question comes, why I cannot see the traffic on charles proxy without modifying the `info.plist`?  ( I can see other https call from other applications though)

Comment: MITM is not easy with https. In the case of Charles Proxy you, as the computer administrator, allowed a certificate to be installed by Charles Proxy, this allowed a Charles Proxy https session to be be accepted. Pinning would would not allow this because not just any valid certificate would be allowed but the certificate belonging to the server you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow a MITM attack by Charles. In order to do so, you need to install Charles's certificate on your device. Information on how to do so can be found [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/) on their site.

After correct installation of the certificate, then you need to select the URL, right click and then click "SSL proxying" for the URL.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input , I end up updating Charles version , they mentioned the ATS only is supported after certain version of Charles